# Missing Index, but Index Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm running a procedure and the Execution Plan is tell me:

> Missing Index (Impact 9.80034): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] ON [dbo].[address_issues] ([Reason]) INCLUDE ([System], [Data ID])

The table is dropped and created on the fly, and I create an Index as well

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_Reason-System-DataID] 
ON [SW].[dbo].[address_issues] ([Reason]) 
    INCLUDE (System, [Data ID])
```

Not sure why I am still getting the notice.  Am I not creating it correctly?

I'm using SSMS and SQL Server 2019

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong - the index suggestions are notoriously bad - sometimes so bad, they'll recommend an index that you just created (based on a suggestion) to be created - again! Don't let that throw you off - just ignore it, when it's already there....

Comment: Assuming you're not creating the index in the wrong database.

Comment: The index has an impact of less than 10, I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: Does the actual plan use your index?

Comment: Maybe the better question is why you have a (stored?) procedure that creates a permanent table for temporary use.

Comment: @SMor I pull it into Excel and it's used in some reports and other things, so I need it to persist.

Comment: "System" is one of reserved keywords. Try to create the index using the include statement, INCLUDE ([System], [Data ID]).